# Display excel chart in browser by using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

Hi I want to display excel chart in web page... If any one knows please tell me how to achieve that...

Already I asked the question here but no one answered me, finally I got the solution... so again I post the question with my solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution by using oledb in c#... 
however I can use the data in an Excel sheet, like a database(oledb), and use a charting library for ASP.NET and generate my own charts outside of Excel. It's working very fine for me...